# Textbox mouse click on text c#

Tags: c#

I'm currently stuck in this, and need help. I'm trying to write a simple text-based game in windows forms, where you can choose your own options etc.

I'm using a textbox to display the text in my story, but somehow when I click on the text in it, the mouse acts like it's trying to edit it, even though you can't. The ReadOnly option is set to true, so I can't delete or add new text into it while running, but the mouse-tab-thing keeps blinking, like you're about to write/delete text. How do I disable this?

Or if you can recommend me to use something else than windows forms to create a text-based game, i'm all ears.

Thank you

Comment: ReadOnly means that you can still click on the text to select it and copy or move the caret in any postion you like. If you don't want any interaction with the textbox then use the Enabled=False property

Comment: If you don't want it to be editable, why use a `TextBox` at all?  Just use a `Label` or something like that.

Comment: Steve, If I set Enable to false, the Textbox will become gray-ish, making it somehow seem less focusing, although that's the only thing you need to focus on. 

David, creating a label won't let me have a scrollbar in the text

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use WinForms to build your Text Game, but why don't you just render directly to the Form using GDI+ ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cksxshce(v=vs.110).aspx

OnPaint is also available on the Form:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{

e.Graphics.DrawString("Amazing story, yeah.",
    new Font("Arial",10), System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, new Point(30,30));
}
```